# Copy parent text to child and remove part of string

Tags: html, jquery

I have a span that is cloned and appended to it, so its created a child with the same text and tag as parent. I need to remove part of string of child element that is before character '@' and for the parent element I need to remove the part of string that is after '@'. So the result will be:

- some textanother text
- some textanother text

```js
 $('.parent').each(function(){
          $(this).clone().appendTo(this).children();
        });
    
        $('.parent span').html(function(i, htm){
          var textP = $('.parent .parent').text();
           return htm.substr(textP.indexOf("@") + 1);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
     <li>
      <span class="parent">some text @ another text</span>
     </li>
     <li>
      <span class="parent">some text @ another text</span>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you need to remove/add from your description  or code.  You can obviously find the @ character, but in the the text that follows it, what isn't it that separates the text you want to keep from what you want to remove?

Comment: A list of demands is hardly a request for help.

Comment: I need to remove part of string of child element that is before character '@' and for the parent element I need to remove the part of string that is after '@'. So parent is 'some text @ another text' => 'some text' and child is 'some text @ another text' => 'another text'

Comment: Use `.replace()`